# EF DefaultIfEmpty where statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have three tables and I am trying to get the Customer Response. This Customer has not Answer the question so in the `MeetingPollingResponseValues` `CustomerId is null` as well as `MeetingPollingPartsValuesId`. But I need to have that where `(mppss.MeetingPollingPartsId == MeetingPollingPartsId && mppvs.CustomerId == CustomerId)` for when Customer has data in that table. I have a the `DefaultIfEmpty` so I  not sure if I need to add `or` to the where statement?

DB Tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MeetingPollingParts](
    [MeetingPollingPartsId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MeetingPollingQuestionId] [int] NULL,
    [MeetingPollingPartsTypeId] [int] NULL
  )
  
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MeetingPollingPartsValues](
    [MeetingPollingPartsValuesId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MeetingPollingPartsValuesTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [MeetingPollingPartsId] [int] NULL
    )
       
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MeetingPollingResponseValues](
    [MeetingPollingResponseValuesId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MeetingPollingPartsValuesId] [int] NULL,
    [CustomerId] [int] NULL
)
```

DB

```
  QuestionValue| MeetingPollingPartsId| MeetingPollingPartsValuesId| CustomerId
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------          
    Yes        | 588                  | NULL                       | NULL
    No         | 588                  | NULL                       | NULL
```

EF

```
var MeetingPollingParticipantsAnswers = (from mppss in db.MeetingPollingParts
        join mppv in db.MeetingPollingPartsValues on mppss.MeetingPollingPartsId equals mppv.MeetingPollingPartsId
        join mppvs in db.MeetingPollingResponseValues on mppv.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId equals mppvs.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId into actualAnswers
        from mppvs in actualAnswers.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where (mppss.MeetingPollingPartsId == MeetingPollingPartsId && mppvs.CustomerId == CustomerId)
                select new Model.MeetingPollingParticipantsAnswers
                {
                Question = mppv.QuestionValue,
                Selected = aa.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId == aa.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId ? true : false,
                MeetingPollingPartsValuesId = aa.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not clear from your message what is happening, or what you want to behave differently!

Comment: You did a good job providing the background info, but I'm not clear on what is going wrong!

Comment: so In my table MeetingPollingResponseValues there is nulls for CustomerId with is correct because this Customer didnt complete the question. But I also want to return this data because at some point they will have data in that table.

Comment: Then you should use a left join instead of an inner join.

Comment: is that what I have with `into actualAnswers from mppvs in actualAnswers.DefaultIfEmpty()`?

Comment: `CustomerID` (as in `mppvs.CustomerId == CustomerId`)  is a C# variable?  If it isn't, what is it?

Comment: Okay, I understand that there's no data for this customer in those tables. What is it that you want to return when there is no such data? The same structure, but with nulls where the answers would be?

Comment: Incidentally, `aa.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId == aa.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId` will always be true since they're the same expression: I think you might have made a typo there!